# 2-D Wavelet output changing when using 'figure' command in Matlab

Tags: wavelet

I am having trouble understanding what is causing the problem to my Wavelet output when i am trying to display the image with the figure command.

I want to display both the Original image and its Wavelets decomposition,
but when I'm using this code the original image is not displaying in a separate figure.

Here is my code,

```
im = imread('cameraman.tif');
imshow(im),title('Original Image')

[cA1,cH1,cV1,cD1] = dwt2(im,'bior3.7');
A1 = upcoef2('a',cA1,'bior3.7',1);
H1 = upcoef2('h',cH1,'bior3.7',1);
V1 = upcoef2('v',cV1,'bior3.7',1);
D1 = upcoef2('d',cD1,'bior3.7',1);

% To display the results of the level 1 decomposition, type:


subplot(2,2,1); image(wcodemat(A1,192));
title('Approximation A1')

subplot(2,2,2); image(wcodemat(H1,192));
title('Horizontal Detail H1')

subplot(2,2,3); image(wcodemat(V1,192));
title('Vertical Detail V1')

subplot(2,2,4); image(wcodemat(D1,192));
title('Diagonal Detail D1')
```

and the output of this code is just one figure with four plots (Digonal, Horizontal, Vertical details and Approximations)

[image]

but when I'm using `figure` command to display the original image in a separate figure,

```
 im = imread('cameraman.tif');
imshow(im),title('Original Image')
figure
```

it messes up the wavelet output,

[image]

Why does it happens that my output is changed to blue and red color ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasoning is simple. MATLAB defaults to a 'jetblue' colormap when you use imshow(im).

Typically you need to specify the colormap being used when you use imshow.

For this, add another command like:

$$colormap(gray(256));$$

to your current script.